# Open Internet Explorer 9 in a new session

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I'd like to create a shortcut to Internet Explorer 9 that opens a new window in a new session. It could be a direct shortcut to IE, or a shortcut to a script (VBScript or Javascript) that does the job.

I know I can click **`File`** + **`New session`**, but I'm looking for a "Quick Launch" or "Desktop" or "Start Menu" shortcut.

If I open let's say 3 IE windows, and then from Taskmgr.exe, I locate one of the IE windows and perform "End Process", all 3 IE windows will close.

If I open the 3 IE windows using "New Session", and then use Taskmgr.exe to "End Process" on one of the IE windows, the other 2 IE windows remain open.

For earlier versions of IE, there used to be a command line option "-new" to open a new IE window in a new session. I've tried this with IE9 but it doesn't seem to work. It opens a new IE window, but it seems the new window is in the same session as the other IE windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"I'd like to create a shortcut to Internet Explorer 9 that opens a new window in a new session."**

**Reference** [IE Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

Using `-new` is no longer possible:

> **-new    Obsolete as of Internet Explorer 7.**

However, there is a new command line option `-noframemerging` which will do what you want:

> **-noframemerging**   Internet Explorer 8 and later versions. Prevents Internet Explorer from opportunistically merging new frame processes
>   into existing frame processes.

**Reference** [IE8 and Reliability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/28/ie8-and-reliability.aspx):

> **Frame Process Merging**
>
> To help improve startup performance, we have  reduced the number of
>   processes that we start. Instead of firing up two processes every time
>   you launch the browser (one for the frame and one for your tabs), we
>   now only fire up one frame process the first time you launch IE.
>   Subsequent launches will only start a new tab process or make a new
>   tab in an existing tab process.
>
> For users that are accustomed to browsing websites in multiple
>   “sessions”, for example if you want to log in to multiple email sites
>   simultaneously, you can specify the **-nomerge** command line option to
>   disable this feature.

The above link was referring to IE 8 Beta 2. In the final release `-nomerge` was renamed to `-noframemerging`.

**Conclusion:**

Replace `-new` with `-noframemerging` in your shortcut command.